# Problema de arrays em C

Tags: c, array

Boa tarde, basicamente estou a tentar fazer um programa que vai pedir ao utilizador para introduzir 10 numeros entre 1 e 100 e com um menu em que o menu vai ter 5 opções neste momento estou na opção 3 em que queria que quando eu clicasse na opção 3 o programa iria pegar no vetor2 e apresenta-se os numeros impares e depois os numeros pares, mas por alguma razão ele esta a introduzir valores random quando vou apresentar os numeros.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <locale.h>

main(){

int i;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int vetor1[10];
int vetor2[10];
int vetor3[10];
int vetorpar[10];
int vetorimpar[10];
int soma = 0;
int perg = 1;
int media;


setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){ //introdução de 10 valores
     printf("\nEscreva um numero de 1 a 100 : ");
     scanf("%i", &vetor1[i]);
      }

for(b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){ //Armazenar o vetor1 no vetor2 e ver se são impares ou pares os numeros
    vetor2[b] = vetor1[b];

    if(vetor2[b] % 2 != 0)
    {
        vetorimpar[b] = vetor2[b];
    }
    else{
        vetorpar[b] = vetor2[b];
    }

       }



 while(perg != 0)
{
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\n 0 - Sair\n 1 - Soma\n 2 - Inversa do Vetor\n 3 - Numeros impares e Pares\n 4 - Arroz\n 5 - Rand\n Digite a opção desejada :  ");
    scanf("%i", &perg);
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");


               switch (perg){

          case 0:
            printf("\n Obrigado pela sua escolha, volte sempre.\n\n");
            system("pause");
            break;

        case 1:

            soma = vetor1[0] + vetor1[1] + vetor1[2] + vetor1[3] + vetor1[4] + vetor1[5] + vetor1[6] + vetor1[7] + vetor1[8] + vetor1[9]; //soma de todos os valores do vetor1
            media = soma / 10; //media da soma dos valores do vetor1
            printf("\n A media é : %i", media);
            break;


        case 2:
            for(c = 9; c >= 0 ; c--){
            printf("\nOrdem inversa : %i", vetor2[c]); //inverso dos valores do vetor1
        }
            break;

        case 3:
             for(d = 0 ; d < 10 ; d++){
                    if(vetorpar[d] != NULL){
                         printf("\nval par : %i", vetorpar[d]); //apresentação dos valores pares do vetor2
                    }

                    else{
                        printf("\nval par : %i", vetorimpar[d]); //apresentação dos valores impares do vetor2
                    }

                      }

        break;

        case 4:
            printf("");
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("");
            break;

        default :
            printf("");

    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Mostrar o código e dizer que ele tem problemas sem especificar que problemas são esses costuma resultar em alerta da equipe do stackoverflow.

Comment: tenta formular um pouco melhor sua pergunta, está realmente complicado interpretar o que você tem como dúvida.

Comment: Como a quantidade pares e ímpares podem ser diferentes utilize diferentes índices para `vetorimpar` e `vetorpar` partindo de 0 e só incrementando quando encontrar um ímpar ou um par.

Comment: ok obrigado pela ajuda mas ja consegui fazer sozinho, talvez escrevi mal sim, mas a interpretação do codigo nao é assim tao complicada basicamente o codigo vai pedir ao utilizador numeros entre 1 e 100 e o utilizador vai introduzir esses numeros 10 vezes depois o codigo vai fornecer 5 opções e o utilizador vai ter de escolher uma dos opçoes a 1 opçao faz a media a segunda faz a inversao do vetor2 e a terçeira era suposto escrever os numeros impares primeiro e depois os pares e o que estava a acontecer eu estava a tentar meter os numeros pares noutra array e os numeros impares noutra array

Comment: e depois eu so queria apresentar com um ciclo for as duas arrays mas nao estava a dar porque a array estava a assumir valores random por algum motivo e estava a apresentar numeros que nao eram suposto aparecer ou seja se os numeros pares fossem 2 4 6 8 10 ele tambem apresentava numeros random e ficava 31231231, 2 , 2898328432, 4, 28927323 ,8, 12318231, 10

Comment: basicamente o que eu mudei foi os ciclos entao fica assim :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então o codigo certo fica assim :

*Codigo Errado : *

```
for(b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){ //Armazenar o vetor1 no vetor2 e ver se são impares ou pares os numeros
vetor2[b] = vetor1[b];

if(vetor2[b] % 2 != 0)
{
    vetorimpar[b] = vetor2[b];
}
else{
    vetorpar[b] = vetor2[b];
}
   }
```

*Codigo certo : *

```
for(b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){ //Armazenar o vetor1 no vetor2
    vetor2[b] = vetor1[b];
}
```

*Parte do Case 3 que estava errada : *

```
 case 3:
         for(d = 0 ; d < 10 ; d++){
                if(vetorpar[d] != NULL){
                     printf("\nval par : %i", vetorpar[d]); //apresentação dos valores pares do vetor2
                }

                else{
                    printf("\nval par : %i", vetorimpar[d]); //apresentação dos valores impares do vetor2
                }
                     }
```

*Codigo Corrigido : *

```
 case 3:
             for(d = 0 ; d < 10 ; d++){
                    if(vetor2[d] % 2 != 0 )
                    {
                       printf("\n Numeros Impares : %i", vetor2[d]);
                    }

                    }

              for(d = 0 ; d < 10 ; d++){
                    if(vetor2[d] % 2 == 0 )
                    {
                       printf("\n Numeros Pares : %i", vetor2[d]);

                    }

                    }
                       break;
```

***Não se esqueçam de remover os vetores pares e impares do codigo em cima que nao faz falta nenhuma!***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que sugeri, que permite até que em sua entrada exista 0, foi:
int qtpar=0, qtimpar=0;
for(b = 0; b < 10 ; b++){
 vetor2[b] = vetor1[b];
 if(vetor2[b] % 2 != 0) {
  vetorimpar[qtimpar++] = vetor2[b];
 }
 else {
  vetorpar[qtpar++] = vetor2[b];
 }
}
printf("\n%d ímpares\n", qtimpar);
for (i=0; i<qtdimpar; i++) {
 printf("\t%d", vetorimpar[i]);
}
printf("\n%d pares\n", qtimpar);
for (i=0; i<qtdpar; i++) {
 printf("\t%d", vetorpar[i]);
}

Comment: ok muito obrigado agradeço :))